# Getting a 404 when trying to load index.jsp using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Even after checking other answers and comparing the code with other applications that I have developed, I can't get to load index.jsp properly. I'm working with Spring MVC, using annotations. The thing is that I have done the same before and it has worked, what could my error be this time?

**MvcConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "tool.controller" })
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String VIEW_CONTROLLER = "/index.htm";
    private static final String VIEW_NAME = "/view/index.jsp";

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController(VIEW_CONTROLLER).setViewName(VIEW_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(final DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**WebInitializer:**

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        context.register(BasicConfig.class, MvcConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher;

        dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
            new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

**IndexController:**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    private static final String INDEX_VIEW = "/view/index.jsp";

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/index" })
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(INDEX_VIEW);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

**Folder Structure:**

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX1Sr.png)

**Console messages from Tomcat initiallization that could be relevant:**

[Console messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vmrS.png)

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT: build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin:'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin:'idea'


ext.springVersion='4.1.4.RELEASE'
ext.hibernateVersion='4.3.8.Final'
ext.hibernateValidatorVersion='5.1.3.Final'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.10'
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.2'

    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'


    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.3.0.RELEASE'
    compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-tx:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-orm:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-aop:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$springVersion"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-oxm:$springVersion"

    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.1.3.RELEASE"

    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:$hibernateVersion"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:$hibernateVersion"    
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:$hibernateValidatorVersion"
    compile "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final"

    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc41'

    compile 'javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:2.3.1'
    compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'

    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

eclipse {
    project.natures "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature"
}
```

Comment: can you share your gradle ?

Comment: My first suggestion , create a WEb-INF/view/index.jsp folder under webapp

Comment: Tried doing the above and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: You are missing a view resolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have apparently found what was the problem. First of all, I'm working on Eclipse IDE. The solution that I came to was adding the folder "webapp" to the "Web Deployment Assembly" in the project's properties. After doing this, the index.jsp is loading properly and I'm not getting a 404 error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Also try to modify your controller class according to spring's good practices.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    //private static final String INDEX_VIEW = "/view/index.jsp";


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/index" })
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```